# Apollo link middleware to update and retry request with non error response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, apollo-link

I am trying to write apollo link middleware which will retry certain requests using a value returned in the payload of the initial failure. I can see the request is being correctly retried, but the middleware is not correctly returning the retry response in the apollo link chain. I can see when adding a logging middleware just before the below, nothing is returned although the request is successfully made.

How would I get this middleware to correctly return the retried result?

```
export const handlerVersionMismatch: ApolloLink = new ApolloLink(
  (operation: Operation, forward: NextLink) => {
    return new Observable<FetchResult>((observer) => {
      let retry = true;

      const handleResponse = (response: FetchResult) => {
        if (retry && handleVersionMismatch(response)) {
          const newVersion = response.data?.cart?.version;
          operation.variables.version = newVersion;
          retry = false;
          forward(operation).subscribe(observer);
        } else {
          observer.next(response);
        }
      };

      const subscription = forward(operation).subscribe({
        next: handleResponse,
        error: (err) => observer.error(err),
        complete: () => observer.complete(),
      });

      // Clean up the subscription when observer is completed or errored
      return () => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      };
    });
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with how the retry response is returned in the Apollo Link chain.

```
...
const handleResponse = (response: FetchResult) => {
        if (retry && handleVersionMismatch(response)) {
          const newVersion = response.data?.cart?.version;
          operation.variables.version = newVersion;
          retry = false;
          return forward(operation).subscribe(observer); // Add return
        } else {
          observer.next(response);
        }
      };
...
```